# out-of-memory exception even though enough memory seems to be available

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, large-object-heap

Occasionally our customers observe an out-of-memory exception in our application. Since we log their actions, we can roughly reproduce what they did, but if I do this and profile the application with dotMemory, I cannot reproduce the exception and the used memory  (around 100 MB managed + 500MB unmanaged) is much less than the limit (2GB, since it is a 32bit application). Also, at the point where the exception is caught the current memory usage is requested using Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 which indicates a memory usage between 500 and 900 MB. I know that this number is not very reliable, but it is another indication that there should be enough memory available.

A relevant property of the application is that it deals with time series of measurements (pairs of DateTime and double stored in an array). These objects may be large enough for being stored at the large object heap (LOH). So, heap fragmentation does occur, but while profiling this did **not** seem to be a big deal. The size of the LOH was less than 100MB **including** the holes.

May it be possible that the garbage collector (GC) is called after an out-of-memory exception is thrown? I would think, that in the case of an unsatisfied memory allocation request the exception is thrown only if the GC fails to collect enough memory. But maybe this is different for memory allocated in the LOH compared to memory allocated in the generation 0 heap?

Does anyone have an idea, how we could tackle this problem?

We are using VS 2010 SP1 and .NET 4.0.
The issue might be related to the question raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33122959/5525302),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15923073/5525302) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3502637/5525302), but I did not find a satisfying answer there.

**Update: Added an exemplary stack trace and a chart of the heap fragementation**

There is no unique place where out-of-memory exceptions are triggered, but since it was requested, I add a strack trace:

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
mscorlib
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator.Rehash()
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(Object obj, Boolean& firstTime)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.InternalGetId(Object obj, Boolean assignUniqueIdToValueType, Type type, Boolean& isNew)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Schedule(Object obj, Boolean assignUniqueIdToValueType, Type type, WriteObjectInfo objectInfo)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteMembers(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo memberTypeNameInfo, Object memberData, WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteMemberSetup(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, String memberName, Type memberType, Object memberData, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, String[] memberNames, Type[] memberTypes, Object[] memberData, WriteObjectInfo[] memberObjectInfos)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
  ... <methods from our application follow>
```

The following chart from dotMemory depicts the LOH fragmentation after working for about an hour with the tool:

[image]

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian - you've linked them to an issue that occurs with .NET 1.1 before service pack 1 is applied to it. Since their question states they're using .NET 4.0, and any .NET predating 3.5 is well out of support, do you think it's likely?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are completely right, i must be slow today only read the symptoms and it fitted.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - The exceptions are not thrown from within any System.Drawing class. They occur during serialization, for instance, or at other places where a significant amount of memory is requested.

Comment: You should take a crash dump first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the tool [vmmap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap.aspx) I found the reason for the problem: The actual memory, which is available for the managed heap, is much less than the 2GB limit. The are several shared libraries loaded for interaction with MS Office tools (~400 MB). There are also native code dlls (~300MB) which also allocate unmanaged heap (~300MB). There is also lot's of other stuff and, in the end, only around 700MB remain for the managed heap.

Since the is much less memory available than I originally thought, the LOH fragmentation may have more impact than I suspected and indeed: vmmap shows, that the largest free block in that memory area becomes smaller over timer, even though the available memory remains the same. I think, this proofs the fragmentation is the cause of the problem. The trigger of the exception is often the binary serialization which we use sometimes for deep copying objects. It seems to cause a peak in memory usage.

So what to do about it? I am considering the following options:

- Switch to x64 (which will happen in the long run anyway)
- Switch to .NET 4.5.1 which allows to [defragment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the LOH
- Reduce general memory usage: It looks like the defragmentation takes much longer if around 200MB is additionally available. This happens when some big libraries are not loaded. In my experiments I could not trigger an out-of-memory-exception anymore.
- Change the code, which will probably be too time consuming

Comment: Could you use a memory pool to eliminate fragmentation?

Comment: I guess yes, but wouldn't that imply reimplementing major parts of C#'s memory management? I fear that is too much effort.