# Does .NET have something similar to what Azul provides for Java?

Tags: java, .net, scalability

[Azul](http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zing/whatisit) provides highly scalable Java solutions which claim to provide very good performance for large applications, both memory and core wise, as opposed to standard Oracle Java on x86 hardware.

Is there something similar in the .NET world?

I know Microsoft has a cloud solution, but does it scale equally well?

Comment: Scale "equally well" is a highly subjective measure.  Perhaps you could give some numbers that you're expecting the .NET implementation to match?  What, specifically, are the features from Azul that you're looking to have duplicated?

Comment: The main selling point of Azuls JVM is that the garbadge collector doesn't have any hard pauses, even with big heaps. That allows to use hunderts of GBs of heap-sizes. Afaik, theirs no such solution available on the .NET space yet.

Answer (score 5):

**No, to the best of my knowledge there isn't anything comparable to Azul or Zing for .NET.**

Part of what Azul got started with was making proprietary CPUs that were *optimized for the Java JVM*. Here is a good [video about that, and why the x86 / x64 architecture has some ... issues](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/click-crash-course-modern-hardware) in modern use.

However, that proprietary hardware product doesn't seem successful in the market. So I guess that Zing could fairly be described as a strategy pivot for Azul: Their original plan was to sell proprietary hardware with a matching highly optimized JVM. Now they're focused on leveraging their optimized JVM, and sell that for use on regular x86 machines.

@Gamlor is right that one of the main selling points of Zing is "hitless garbage collection", or garbage collection which doesn't make the JVM pause. I'm not aware of anyone pushing that for .NET. Perhaps this [answer regarding .NET vs Java GC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492703/net-vs-java-garbage-collector) is interesting.

You could fairly say that [Mono is a competing VM for .NET](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). But to the best of my knowledge, nobody is really selling Mono on being dramatically faster or more scalable than Microsoft .NET.