# Garbage collection performance comparison, java vs .net 4.5

Tags: c#, java, .net, garbage-collection, jvm

In the case of garbage collector performance comparison between .NET 4.5 and Java, is there any detailed comparison which shows their efficiency in different situations?

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492703/net-vs-java-garbage-collector)(.Net vs Java Garbage Collector ) question which has a good answer, but it's as old as about 4 years ago. I think with .NET 4.5 and Java 7, there should be some more optimizations.

Comment: What you could do is place a bounty on the linked question asking for more recent data.

Comment: provide a bounty on the linked/duplicate question